How to switch between control rig and export rig?
I am pretty new to Blender, but I have gotten UE5 Manny imported and I am able to import Unreal animations, tweak them, and export them back to Unreal.
And it's hard to get good poses just directly rotating bones, so after some work I finally managed to get a Rigify control mesh for Manny.
But now I can't figure out how to use the control rig with a loaded animation. It seems that only one of them can drive the mesh. In a scene where Manny is using the Rigify control rig I can't even force the skeletal mesh to follow the animation.
How do you switch between the two so you can use your Rigify rig to adjust a frame of an animation?

"so after some work I finally managed to get a Rigify control mesh for Manny."
Does that mean that you simply rigged Manny with Rigify? Or did you create some sort of a relationship between the Rigify rig and the Manny one? It sounds like it is the former. In which case there is no way to directly exchange animation between them. You might want to look into retargeting

Hi CGDive, I was actually following your tutorial until I got stuck b/c I couldn't get Epic's UE to Rigify to work in 4.2 (and in 3.6 the generated Manny control rig does not match the pose). I ended up using 3.6 and Any Rig to Rigify to get a decent control rig for Manny.
Is there no way to use a control rig to tweak a frame of an existing animation?
I have written a Python script that will take a delta between current pose and a frame of an animation and apply it to all the following frames, which lets me create new animations from existing ones. But tweaking by hand is tedious.
